# Webpack debuging tools

Tags: javascript, webpack

I build my project using webpack and want to be able to look at the code in browser but webpack devtools doesn't appear in browser.
I wonder why? I did everything like they say in a book.

Here is my webpack.config file

```js
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/App.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist", "assets"),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: "#source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is devtools in browser without webpack in it

[image: devtools screenshot]

Why doesn't it appear in the browser devtools?

Comment: What does the network tab say, and what shows in console?

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using? Have a read [here](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/debugging/#devtools)

Comment: Try to (Cmd + P: Mac) or (Ctrl + P: window) then the popup will show, then search your file

Comment: I am using webpack 4.43.0. I tried ctrl+p didnt help. I can have found the bundle.map file

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://dipiagiiohfljcicegpgffpbnjmgjcnf/js/react.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score 1):

You havent set the `mode`, which defaults to `production`. See here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

And it should be `source-map`, without the `#`. Also added `sourceMap` to the module options, see if that helps.

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development', // This
    entry: "./src/App.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist", "assets"),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: "source-map", // This
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    sourceMap: true, // This
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do as you advised it dint help. but I found the error in console:
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://dipiagiiohfljcicegpgffpbnjmgjcnf/js/content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Is the file being generated at all (you have the .map file locally)?

Comment: Yes I do have the map file((

Comment: Ah, then its (mosy likely) not a config problem